# subprocess not catching stdout

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

im trying since days to figure out why my subprocess.Popen does not catch the stdout. Maybe it has something to do with the fact that the subprocess outputs a file. I found this out when I run a subprocess without an output file and the stdout (that you would see at the terminal) was cought. Can you please help me how to catch it in the scenario with the output file, so I dont want to catch the output from the file but only the terminal output, so running output. Any kind of help is very appreciated.

```
     command = "cnvkit.py call %s -o %s" % (file, output)
     process_call = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, cwd=sfs.path('cnv_app/call_CNS/'), universal_newlines=True)
stdout, stderr = process_call.communicate()
     if process_call.returncode and stderr:
          output_call = stdout
          output_err_call = stderr
     else:
          output_call = stdout 
          process_call.poll()
          response = {'output_call': output_call, 'output_err_call': output_err_call}
```

Comment: You might want to share a bit more detail `Popen` with `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` followed by `stdout, stderr = process_call.communicate()` should leave you with `stdout` that is stdout output of the child process. Note: I cannot seem to figure out, why would you get `command` as formatted string and then split it (also risking things fall apart if `file` or `output` had space in them), rather then just defining `command` as `list` or `tuple` to begin with.

Comment: If you're telling the command to output to a specific filename - then that is where the output is, STDOUT is no longer involved.

Comment: @OndrejK. thank you for your note, well yes you are right, it is not save if the input has space, yes I will correct that. But what do you mean by child process, is that the command i execute?

Comment: @jasonharper when I execute the command from terminal I get some information about the running process, it also happens in django terminal when I run it without stdout=subprocess.PIPE. That is what I want, that cannot be lost, or can I not catch it in this case?

Comment: As said, it generally looks OK, it should work like that. With given information the rest is mostly divining from a crystal ball. When you call your other script with `-o`, is it still expected to print anything to stdout? Or not? How do you actually try to use it (and tell it was not captured; as is the indentation suggests you only set response in some cases).

Answer (score 0):

My child process was returning a warning which apparently goes to stderr and since my  `process_call.returncode` would return 0, which is False for the if statement, only the stdout was captured which was empty, and thats why i did not get the output. I am a little dissapointed that the stdout goes all to stderr when a warning appears. Yes you are right, you needed a crystal ball to answer the question, but hey you helped me to solve my Problem :)